# How can I compare columns from 2 different tables?

Tags: sql

I have two tables from two databases:

abc.table1
xyz.table2

How can I check which columns found in table 1 are not in table 2?

### TABLE 1

| id | name | phone_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 111111111111 |
| 2 | Jane | 222222222222 |

### TABLE 2

| id | date | phone_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0945 | 111111111111 |
| 2 | 0950 | 222222222222 |
| 3 | 1045 | 333333333333 |

RESULT:

NAME

(Since the column name is in Table 1 but not found in Table 2)

Comment: you need to use a `join`. Can you please share what you have tried.

Comment: We love that you're here with us and you need to show us an effort so we can help you debug your code.

Comment: which database ? All database has some metadata table - you can compare them.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

Please mentin database name. If you are using sql server then can use below query to get what you are looking for:

```
select COLUMN_NAME from abc.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns  
where TABLE_NAME='TABLE1' and COLUMN_NAME not in (select COLUMN_NAME from 
xyz.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where table_name='TABLE2')
```